# emacs lisp pcase error

Tags: emacs, pattern-matching, elisp

I am having a hard time reading/understanding the syntax of the `pcase` statement in emacs-lisp. Please help me figure out how to make the following a valid `pcase` statement.

```
(defun execute-play (str)
  (setq parse (mapcar (lambda (s) (split-string s ":")) (split-string str " ")))
  (pcase (string-to-char (caar parse))``
      ((pred (<= (string-to-char "5"))) (t-to-pparse))
      ((pred (<= (string-to-char "d"))) (f-to-p parse))
      ((string-to-char "w") (w-to-p parse))
      (_ "bad input")))
```

Note that typical input is "1:2 3" or "a 5".

The error from emacs that I get is: `'edebug-signal: Unknown upattern '(string-to-char w)'`
This is the second to last case, -- I thought that this would just match the value of `(caar parse)` against `(string-to-char "w")` if it did not already match a case before this. Note that I also tried replacing `(string-to-char "w")` with `(SELFQUOTING (string-to-char "w"))` since the documentation says that: `SELFQUOTING matches itself.  This includes keywords, numbers, and strings.`

Please help me get this emacs-lisp pcase statement working -- Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Don't `setq` on a variable (such as `parse`) that you have not locally declared.  Use `let` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. Since you're not doing any binding or deconstruction in your patterns, you don't need `pcase` — the conditional is better written using `cond`.
2. You have a spurious pair of backquotes at the end of line 3.
3. You appear to have inverted the first two tests — the first clause will match if the expression is larger than `?5`, so the remaining clauses will never match.
4. `pcase` doesn't seem to support matching against evaluated values, so third clause should be written `(pred (equal (string-to-char "0")))`.